# VS2015 Add Assembly File Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I want to browse for assemblies I want to reference I got the following error (bottom left of the dialog) saying "Project does not have target frameworks specified"

What do I have to define it ?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short after posting i found the solution

I had to extend the project.json with the target framework like for dnx 4.5.1

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { },
    "dnx451": { }     }
```